# FPC Connector on a Laser Distance Module

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable, fpc

I recently purchased some RS232 laser distance modules from overseas and I'm just in the process of trying to get them going. Basically it takes 4 I/O's - Ground, + 3VDC, TX, RX.

It has an 8 way FPC 0.5mm connector on it which can be used for the TX and RX, however I want to go from that, to individual leads so I can connect them up to the USB interface for the RS232.

What adaptors are available for converting from FPC to Individual connectors, (aside from buying a FPC jumper cable and trying to pull the strands apart)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic on EE.SE. In any case, have you googled "FPC breakout board"?

Comment: I'd just take that sucker off and blue wire right to the board, make sure you provide strain relief